# What is the 'instance' keyword argument alternative for forms.Form?

Tags: django, forms

I am using django for saving in database. In my view function, I used:

```
form = RecipeForm(instance=Recipe)
```

where Recipe is the name of my model.

When I go to the url, I get the following error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

I have searched around and found that 'instance' is specifically for model forms. Is there any alternative for forms.Form. If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

This is my full function in views.py

```
def recipe_edit(request, pk):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST, instance=Recipe)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            recipe.user = request.user
            recipe.save()
            return redirect('recipe_detail', pk=recipe.pk)
    else:
        form = RecipeForm(instance=Recipe)
    return render(request, 'recipe_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is my form in forms.py

```
class RecipeForm(forms.Form):   
    title= forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Comment: Why not just use a model form?

Comment: Its because of the way my app works, i can only use forms.Form because many things are added manually in forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) dictionary when instantiating the form.

```
initial = {'title': recipe.title, 'description': recipe.description}
form = RecipeForm(initial=initial)
```

Comment: your solution might work. Do you what should I use as action="" in the form?
My url is like this: url(r'^recipe_edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.recipe_edit, name='recipe_edit'), When I edit a post, it loads as: /recipe_edit/5/ where 5 is the pk of recipe

Comment: If you are submitting to the current url, your form doesn't need an `action` at all. If you want to include the action, you could use the url tag and do `action="{% url 'recipe_edit' recipe.pk %}"`. Note you will need to add the `recipe` to the context dict in your `render()` call in the view, so that the url tag can access the recipe in the template.